# Как получить координаты обьекта в изображении?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow, pyautogui

Есть скрипт, который делает первый скриншот

```
def screenshot_one(self):
        image_1 = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (5, 169, 1427, 559))
        image_1.save(r'{}\data\screenshot\image_1.png'.format(self.BASE_DIR))
        return image_1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И второй скриншот

```
def screenshot_two(self):
        image_2 = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (5, 169, 1427, 559))
        image_2.save(r'{}\data\screenshot\image_2.png'.format(self.BASE_DIR))
        return image_2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем находит между ними разницу

```
def comparison(self, image_1, image_2):
        result = ImageChops.difference(image_1, image_2)
        result.save(r'{0}\data\screenshot\screen.png'.format(self.BASE_DIR))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить координаты объекта на экране `1920х1080`, который скрипт выделил как отличие между первым и вторым скриншотом, то есть координаты белого круга на третьем скриншоте?

Код целиком

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image, ImageChops
from pathlib import Path
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time

class Object_search:
    def __init__(self):
        self.BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

    def screenshot_one(self):
        image_1 = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (5, 169, 1427, 559))
        image_1.save(r'{}\data\screenshot\image_1.png'.format(self.BASE_DIR))
        return image_1

    def screenshot_two(self):
        image_2 = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (5, 169, 1427, 559))
        image_2.save(r'{}\data\screenshot\image_2.png'.format(self.BASE_DIR))
        return image_2

    def comparison(self, image_1, image_2):
        result = ImageChops.difference(image_1, image_2)
        result.save(r'{0}\data\screenshot\screen.png'.format(self.BASE_DIR))

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('5'):
        print('image_1')
        image_1 = Object_search().screenshot_one()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('6'):
        image_2 = Object_search().screenshot_two()
        print('image_2')
        time.sleep(0.1)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('7'):
        print('comparison')
        comparison = Object_search().comparison(image_1, image_2)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('8'):
        print('exit')
        break
```

Comment: Переходите на OpenCV. На версии 2.x с ним не работал, но, думаю, отличий мало.

Comment: на python 2.7 не встанет OpenCV, я бы с удовольствием перешел, но необходимо реализовать задуманное именно на python 2.7

Comment: Что на счет [v4.2.0.32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346648/python-2-7-installing-opencv-via-pip-virtual-environment)

Comment: Сработало, можете дать наводку куда смотреть в OpenCV, чтобы реализовать описанную выше задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img = cv2.imread("MYIMG.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
(_, _, _, coords) = cv2.minMaxLoc(img)
```

coords - левый верхний угол круга.

### UPD

Откопал из старых проектов еще один вариант:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("AFQZB.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# img=cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

(_, threshold)=cv2.threshold(img, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
(contours, _)=cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for rect in contours:
    (x, y, width, height)=cv2.boundingRect(rect)
    print(x, y, width, height)
    # ...
```

Вывод:

```
411 158 222 214
```

Comment: Шикарно, дальше сам копаться буду, спасибо)